# Increase session timeout in asp.net 2.0 on IIS 6.1 with windows 2008 R2 Datacenter

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, session-timeout

I stuck in increasing timeout for websites in asp.net 2.0 on IIS 6.1 with windows 2008 R2 Datacenter.

thx for help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If your using the sessionState property of ASP.NET 2.0 Then you can adjust the `timeout` in your web.config

```
<sessionState 
mode="InProc" 
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
sqlCommandTimeout="30" 
customProvider="" 
cookieless="UseCookies" 
cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
timeout="20"  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
partitionResolverType="" 
useHostingIdentity="true">
<providers>
  <clear />
</providers>
 </sessionState>
```

Have a peek at the [MSDN Documentation of the sessionState attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thx for your feedback. I used this configuration but still my session does not last long enough

Comment: Just increase the timeout to whatever you wish.